# monitors.xml is ignored, Monitor Preferences GUI tool doesn't work

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

Ubuntu Mate 22.04.1
I recently upgraded a monitor in my previously working 3 monitor system and now my ~/.config/monitors.xml file (and the GUI Monitor Preferences tool) is being ignored. It seems like an ad-hoc monitor setup is being generated as though monitors.xml doesn't exist.
I've created an xrandr startup script which builds a volatile monitors profile on every login. This partially works in that my desktop now displays on the monitor I want as my primary display. However most of my programs are picking up the primary display from somewhere else. This means, for example, that when I start Libre Office Writer it opens by default on a monitor I cannot see.
Permissions on monitors.xml are 664.
Thanks.